# bootstrap form-inline not rendering properly with d3

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm creating an interactive visualization using [d3.js](https://d3js.org/); the top of the visualization has a GUI which I'm styling with [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/).  I'm trying to style the GUI as a `.form-inline`, however the labels for the checkboxes are not showing and the spacing between the `.form-group` isn't working.

## Rendered html:

[image: rendered GUI]

## Rendered code:

[image]

## JS code

For the checkboxes I'm using (where selector is the div ID that everything is being rendered in):

```
var gui = d3.select(selector).append("div")
    .attr("id", "gui")
    .attr("class","form-inline")

gui.append("div")
    .attr("class","checkbox")
    .append("label")
    .append("input")
    .attr("type","checkbox")
    .attr("id","toggle_distance")
    .attr("checked","")
    .attr("onclick","guiUpdate(this)")
    .text(" Toggle distance labels")
```

For the dropdown I'm using:

```
var leafSelect = gui.append("div")
    .attr("class","form-group")
    .append("select")
    .attr('onchange','guiUpdate(this)')
    .attr('id','leafColor')
    .attr("class","form-control")

leafSelect.selectAll("option")
    .data(mapParse.keys()).enter()
    .append("option")
    .text(function(d) { return d; })
```

Looking at the [bootstrap form examples](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms), it looks like everything should be rendering properly.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm solving the checkbox label issue with the following:

```
var gui = d3.select(selector).append("div")
    .attr("id", "gui")
    .attr("class","form-inline")

var check1 = gui.append("div")
    .attr("class","checkbox")
    .append("label")

check1.append("input")
    .attr("type","checkbox")
    .attr("id","toggle_distance")
    .attr("checked","")
    .attr("onclick","guiUpdate(this)")

check1.append('text')
    .text("Toggle distance labels")
```

The alignment issue I'm patching into place with some CSS unfortunately:

```
.form-inline text, .form-inline label {
    margin: 0px 3px 0px 3px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the checkbox problem: move the text outside the `input`and inside the `label`:

```
gui.append("div")
   .attr("class","checkbox")
   .append("label")
   .text(" Toggle distance labels")
   .append("input")
   .attr("type","checkbox")
   .attr("id","toggle_distance")
   .attr("checked","")
   .attr("onclick","guiUpdate(this)")
```

Now, for the spacing problem, this is a guess: append `form` instead of `div`:

```
var gui = d3.select(selector).append("form")
   .attr("id", "gui")
   .attr("class","form-inline")
```

And the inner div like you did:

```
var leafSelect = gui.append("div")
   .attr("class","form-group")
   .append("select")
   .attr('onchange','guiUpdate(this)')
   .attr('id','leafColor')
   .attr("class","form-control")
```

Comment: The checkbox solution works, but I'd like the label to be to the right of the checkbox (just like in the bootstrap example).  As for your guess on the spacing, that didn't resolve anything.